# How to get Remaining Amount of Customer Deposits in Saved Search (includes SuiteScript code)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I need to get the **Remaining Balance** of all **Customer Deposits** linked to a specific **Sales Order**

**Remaining Balance** = the available/unapplied amount

Below, I will show you how I solved this in a saved search.
As a bonus, I'll also include the SuiteScript 1.0 code to do the same.

Comment: you did not include your code example.

Comment: @lancegerday Yes I did. It's at the bottom of the answer... Am I meant to provide something more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the **Remaining Amount** of all **Customer Deposits** linked to a specific **Sales Order** record:

Create a Transaction Saved Search as follows:

- Criteria (Use Expressions)

  - ( **Type** IS **Deposit Application** AND
  - **Created From Fields > Sales Order** IS **Sales Order #xyz** ) OR
  - ( **Type** IS **Customer Deposit** AND
  - **Created From** IS **Sales Order #xyz** )
    [image: Saved Search Criteria]
- Results

  - **Formula (Numeric)** (Summary type **SUM**): `CASE WHEN {type} = 'Customer Deposit' THEN {debitamount} ELSE -{creditamount} END`
    [image: Saved Search Results]

BONUS, SuiteScript 1.0 code to get **Remaining Amount** of all **Customer Deposits** linked to a specific **Sales Order** record:

```
function customerDepositsRemainingBalance(salesorder_internalid) {
    var filters = [[["type","anyof","DepAppl"],"AND",["createdfrom.salesorder","anyof",salesorder_internalid]],"OR",[["type","anyof","CustDep"],"AND",["createdfrom","anyof",salesorder_internalid]]];
    var columns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('formulanumeric',null,'SUM')];
    columns[0].setFormula("CASE WHEN {type} = 'Customer Deposit' THEN {debitamount} ELSE -{creditamount} END");
    var search = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction',null,filters,columns);

    if(search == null) return 0;
    return Number(search[0].getValue(columns[0]));
}

// Example Usage
balance = customerDepositsRemainingBalance(3247434); // returns 50
balance = customerDepositsRemainingBalance(3256644); // returns 0
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Please note that the search filter is bloated. You can get the same with Created From = SO# AND Type anyof (Deposit Application, Customer Deposit).